# Set Audience targetting on left naviagtion with Javascript/Jquery

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365

I want to **set Audience targeting on left navigation** bar of **SharePoint**, though there are around 50 links on which i need to set the targeting on. Every time I take a template and restore it, I manually need to update targeting again and again. 
Is there a way to set audience targeting on navigation with the help of `javascript/JQuery`?

I am using office 365/ SharePoint online.

Thanks!